# Why is group_by and mutate giving me the unexpected result?

Tags: r

This is an excerpt of my dataset:

```
check = structure(list(currency = c("AED", "ATS", "AUD", "BEF", "BND", 
"CAD"), year = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005), value = c(0, 
0, 14628, 0, 27, 1604), month = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"
), quarter = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Running this code:

```
check2 = check %>% group_by(currency) %>% mutate(sum = sum(value))
```

gives me

```
currency  year value  month   quarter   sum
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 AED       2005     0 1           1 16259
2 ATS       2005     0 1           1 16259
3 AUD       2005 14628 1           1 16259
4 BEF       2005     0 1           1 16259
5 BND       2005    27 1           1 16259
6 CAD       2005  1604 1           1 16259
```

Shouldn't it give me a different value for each currency? When I tried to group by different combinations of variables, it gives me the same value 16259. Could someone point out where I did it wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Try with `dplyr::mutate` could be masking from `plyr::mutate`

Comment: Add more data. The data you have provided would produce this outcome.

Comment: @akash87: If I group_by(currency) it should give me a different result for each currency, no? Since each currency has a different value for each year, month, quarter.

Comment: @akrun: Yes this works! I unloaded `plyr` and it gave me the right answer now. No wonder why it worked at the beginning but then stopped working at some point. It was because I loaded `plyr` for another project. Thank you! Side question: how do I specify that the function `mutate` I want to use is from `dplyr` and not `plyr`? Also, what's the difference between these two mutate functions? I checked the documentation and they were supposedly similar in functionality but clearly not in this case.